# Why is this code not receiving UDP packets?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I wrote some code that requests 1000 data packets of size 4094 over UDP from another source (192.168.10.2), and used Wireshark to confirm the data is arriving at my host (192.168.10.1) - with source port 1234 and dest 4321, but my processing code hangs on recvfrom.  Am I using this incorrectly in the code snippet below?

```
int sockfd;
char buffer[4094];
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

FILE* f = fopen("output.bin", "wb");

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0){
    perror("error creating socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(4321);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.10.2");

bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

int n;
socklen_t len;

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 4094, MSG_WAITALL, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);
    if (n>0){
        if (n<4094){
            buffer[n] = '\0';
        }
        fwrite(buffer, 1, n, f);
    }
}

fclose(f);
close(sockfd);
```

Comment: Side notes: a) make sure that your network can handle a 4K UDP message. b) UDP is all or nothing, so `MSG_WAITALL` is probably meaningless.

Comment: no problem with the network, this is just over a simple 10G ethernet link - I maxed out the network buffers and the host can process fast enough, some data loss is fine for this application too - is there a better flag to have in that case?


`IPPROTO_UDP` didn't make any difference for me

Comment: len has not been initialised.

Comment: also you did not bind the socket to the port

Comment: You don't pass the socket address to `recvfrom`. That's an output argument which tells you where the packet came *from*. You need to call `bind` with the server address.

Comment: `char buffer[4094];` -- `n = recvfrom... ` -- `buffer[n] = '\0';` -- What happens if `recvfrom` returns -1?  What happens if `recvfrom` returns 4094?

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), 4094, f);` -- You should be using the value of `n` to determine how many bytes to write to the file, not `sizeof(buffer)`.  Also from my previous comment, you really shouldn't be sticking null bytes into what is returned.

Comment: @paulmckenzie. it is not clear from the question if the message should be truncated before it is written to the file, or all 4094 bytes need to be written there.

Comment: sizeof(buffer[0]) should always be 1 if it is char. seems reasonable to me.

Comment: exit(0) should only be used when there is successful end to the process. should probably be exit(EXIT_FAILURE).

Comment: Be cautious about how much you change the question in response to the comments. They may have correctly diagnosed the problem with the code and now you are onto another problem with extremely similar observable results.

Comment: Side note: Paul's point about `recvfrom` returning the max read of 4094 still stands. `buffer[4094] = '\0';` is A buffer overflow.

Comment: Where did `cliaddr` come from? Can we get a [mre] of the current state of the code?

Comment: len needs to be initialised before every invocation of recvfrom.

Comment: apologies - trying to keep up, I think the current state works and still get the same result

Comment: why is this tagged c++, the code style is very much like c99?

Comment: is this on Unix/Linux? - does `netstat -an` confirm the server is listening on the port 4321? I think there is also a similar netstat command in Windows too.  i suspect the problem is you have bound to the wrong address - the binding address should be the address of your local interface, not the client address.

Comment: The bind-address should be 0.0.0.0 unless you have a good reason otherwise. There is not enough error checking in this code. Try it. You might get a surprise.

Comment: that makes sense, I changed the address to be correct - using netstat the address:port shows up but it doesn’t show the state as listen, it is just blank - how do you set it to listen? this is Linux as well yes

Comment: Better to use the proper macro INADDR_ANY than the hard coded address 0.0.0.0.

Comment: still doesn’t show as listening when I use INADDR_ANY

Comment: that's fine if it doesn't show as listening. udp is different to tcp. the main thing to check is it shows that it is bound to Local address `0.0.0.0:4321`.

Comment: It won’t be LISTEN. That’s a TCP state. This is UDP.

Comment: I see - in that case it looks to be in order there, is there another reason why recvfrom would hang in this case?

Comment: Wrong port, wrong IP:port at the sender, or nothing being sent.

Comment: using wireshark I can see the UDP packets with source 192.168.10.2, destination 192.168.10.1, source port 1234, dest port 4321, and 4094 data bytes

Answer (score 0):

You have bound to the client address, you should bind to the local interface address.

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.10.2");
```

should be

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.10.1");
```

or you may prefer this to say it can bind to all interfaces:

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```